# How do I read output of a command through a pipe from a shell script?

Tags: shell

I have a command like

```
cat file | sh myscript.sh
```

How do i read the output of `cat file` into myscript.sh?

Comment: tell exactly what in the file you need as an input to your script?do u want to pass each line at a time to your script?

Comment: No, i want in myscript.sh to handle the entire content of file in a single var

Comment: @curious: If you want whole line until EOF, I provided a solution using `xargs` below along with a few other variations. Although, from your problem description above it's not quite clear what exactly you need.

Answer (score 3):

```
cat file | while read something; do echo "This is $something" ; done
```

The details depend on the nature of your data and your intentions.

Now that you've said you want the whole file in a single variable, it's

```
var="$(cat file)"
```

Comment: i can't understasnd the syntax. while read something will save the "cat file" to variable something?

Comment: `read something` reads the field(s) from the next line of input into specified variables. On a related note, `man bash` gives you some useful information on how it works.

Comment: i've put `while read something; do echo "This is $something" ; done` at the beginning of my script but it doesn't work

Comment: It depends on your expectations, check the  updatd answer

Comment: Yes but how could i read the literal "file" inside myscript.sh. I can't find a way of passing `cat file` to `sh myscript.sh`. When i `echo $1` this is the name of the scipt and not the output of the first part of the pipe

Comment: I put something like this :
`var=""`
`while read input;do var=$var"\n"$input`;done
but it doesn't seem to save the same results as with `cat file`. Actually it removes the \n and when i tried to add manually it adds the "n" value

Comment: I still fail to see what is it you're looking for. Getting the whole file in the variable is `var="$(cat file)"`, no need to read line by line, what do you mean by "literal file" I'm not sure. You want to know the file name when reading from std input?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use `cat`, just pass the file to your script:

```
myscript.sh file
```

Comment: i want exactly the syntax as originally posted

Answer (score 0):

I use something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

cat "$@" | <my commands>
```

That way, if one or more file names are given as arguments, they are passed to <my commands>. If no file is given, `cat` retrieves the standard input and passes it to <my commands>.

Answer (score 0):

This only works if your input does not contain any `NUL` (`\0`) characters - Variables can't contain `NUL` because it's used to set the end of the variable.

```
read -r -d ''
```

Now you can use the `$REPLY` variable, which will contain all the contents of the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use this -- `cat file | sh myscript.sh` -- orientation of piping a file to another shell script, use [xargs](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xargs):

**Content of `file.txt`:**

```
blah1
blah2
blah3
```

**Content of `myscript.sh`:**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
```

Use `xargs` to achieve either of the following:

**Variation 0:**

```
user@host:~$ cat file.txt | xargs -E ./myscript.sh
blah1 blah2 blah3
```

From [xargs man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xargs):

```
-E eof-str
  Set the end of file string to eof-str.  If the end of 
  file string occurs as a  line of  input,  the rest of 
  the input is ignored.  If neither -E nor -e is used, 
  no end of file string is used.
```

**Variation 1:**

```
user@host:~$ cat file.txt | xargs ./myscript.sh 
blah1
```

**Variation 2:**

```
user@host:~$ cat file.txt | xargs --null ./myscript.sh 
blah1 blah2 blah3
```

**Variation 3:**

```
user@host:~$ cat file.txt | xargs -I{} ./myscript.sh {}
blah1
blah2
blah3
```

Mind you, `-I` is limited by maximum character limit per line. This limit can be set by specifying `--max-chars` or `-s` as following:

```
user@host:~$ cat file.txt | xargs -I{} -s 100000 ./myscript.sh {}
blah1
blah2
blah3
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a lot of the current answers are encouraging the OP to read the file in the script, rather than answering the question.  If you are invoking the command:

```
$ cat file | sh myscript.sh
```

and you want the contents of file in a variable, then you simply need to have the script read stdin into a variable.  The easiest way to do that is with cat:

```
#!/bin/sh

v=$(cat)
```

Note that the original command is a UUOC, and could be done with:

```
$ < file sh myscript.sh
```

or

```
$ sh myscript.sh < file
```

Also note that reading stdin into the variable v will read until stdin is closed, so that if you invoke myscript.sh directly (ie, with stdin on a tty), it will block until the user hits ^d (or whatever key sequence indicates EOF on the platform.)  It really is a better idea to pass the filename as an argument to the script.